# Contiki debugging workflow: How to see logs?

Tags: contiki

To understand the code flow of RPL, i have enabled logs in the source code:

`#define DEBUG DEBUG_FULL`

They are by default directed to `UART` which i can then read via a `minicom` console.

So if i want to see RPL behavior of four motes connected to a bridge, i need to have all five of then hooked to five laptops. Is the following flow possible-

1. Redirect the logs to a file that gets saved on the file system.
2. Remotely log-in to the mote.
3. Tail all the logs from my laptop into say 5 terminals.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes

Longer answer: Contiki comes with `serialdump` which does exactly what you want. You can run `make serialdump` to log the serial input to a file.